# Separate MySQL tables for plugins

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-schema

I am working on some project where should be something like plugins and core of my website provide them API (access to user informations etc). But now I am solving one problem - each plugin should have his own database tables to store informations, but there is no one template for these tables, so plugin must create its own tables with custom structure. What is my issue here?

I need to be sure that every single plugin has access only to tables which it creates. These plugin tables will be in separate database with special credentials (so it can't access "core" tables), but how to avoid to access tables of other plugins? My idea is following:

- Each plugin will have some unique table prefix (non-public).
- There will be some class for plugins, where will me methods for select, insert etc.

Here is basic example to understand my idea:

```
public function Select($fromTable, $selectWhat, $where) {
   $query = "SELECT " . $selectWhat . " FROM {unique_prefix}_" . $fromTable . " where " . $where . ";";
}
```

It's really simple example without any input protection... And here comes my question - how to secure it to avoid access to another plugins? Let's say they don't know unique prefix of each other, but still. Or how to avoid to pass as `$where` something like `1 = 1; evil code here;`? Of course account for those plugins will have only privileges to SELECT, INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE. Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use prepared statements like with PDO to generate your query, don't let the raw input come. I do not know what you will have in $where, but it will still be a limited amount of items. Thus do something like this: for each item in array generate a part of PDO statement. This way, it will generate a correct query AND, most importantly, neutralize all the "evil code".

[PDO prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: While using prepared statements is certainly better than what the OP shows, it doesn't solve the problem of plugin writers accessing tables they are not supposed to access.

Comment: Well, but I can still have control over main query and use for example unique prefixes. Plugin send me only binds to PDO and action. I am selecting this as answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this is the best solution, but you could create a separate mysql user for each plugin which only has grants to that plugin's tables (Grants: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html).

You'll probably want to force some type of naming convention for each plugin's tables and create a tool that automatically sets the grants for the associated user.